# Extjs 6 and Ext.net in the same project?

Tags: javascript, extjs, compatibility, ext.net, extjs6

is it possible to cohabit **Extjs 6** and **Ext.net** 1.7 in the same project ?
on my side not yet tested, 
I have a project based on Ext.net and I want to introduce Extjs6 components.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify would you need to use ExtJS 6 and Ext.NET 1.7 on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is zero chance of this working.

Ext.NET 1.7 is built using Ext JS 3.4(?). There were major breaking changes introduced by Sencha in Ext JS 4.x. Ext JS 5 was mostly compatible with Ext JS 4, although still not a drop in replacement. Ext JS 6 is not a drop in replacement for Ext JS 5.

So, no.